# Use class template as callback in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++03

I was able to make the callback work without class templates. But my requirement is to implement callbacks with passing class objects which are in template form. I have written my intent in the main(), but somehow I am unable to make it work.

I cannot use boost and C++11 for my current issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// TestProj.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "glb.h"
#include "Test.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyCallBack
{
private:
    class Callback
    {
    public:
        virtual ~Callback() { }
        virtual void call() = 0;
    };

    template <typename T>
    class ClassCallback : public Callback
    {
    private:
        T*      object;
        void (T::*callback)();

    public:
        ClassCallback(T* obj, void (T::*clbk)()) : object(obj), callback(clbk) {}
        virtual void call() { (object->*callback)(); }
    };

private:
    Callback*       callback;

public:
    MyCallBack() : callback(NULL) { }
    ~MyCallBack() { delete callback; }

    template <typename T>
    MyCallBack(T* obj, void (T::*clbk)())
    {
        callback = new ClassCallback<T>(obj,clbk);
    }

    void operator () ()
    {
        callback->call();
    }
};

typedef enum {
    EVENT1 = 1,
    EVENT2 = 2,
    EVENT3 = 4,
    EVENT4 = 8
} MyEvent_t;

template <class EventT> 
class EventHandler
{
public:
    virtual void on_event(EventT _event) = 0;
};

class MyHandler:public EventHandler<MyEvent_t>{

    virtual void on_event(MyEvent_t _event){

        switch(_event){

            case EVENT1:
                break;

            case EVENT2:
                break;

        }
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    EventHandler<MyEvent_t> *my_handler = new MyHandler();
    MyCallBack rcb(my_handler,&MyHandler<MyEvent_t>::on_event);

    // to check the callback
    rcb();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot of any leads!!!

Comment: I'm sure we can help you, if you can be more specific as to the issue, and/or reduce the code.

Comment: For starters, `on_event` expects `EventT`. Your `void (T::*callback)();` doesn't account for this.

Comment: HI Barrett,  yes i am aware that argument is missing. My question is how to add it. I am new to C++ and templates. Also the line  MyCallBack rcb(my_handler,&MyHandler<MyEvent_t>::on_event); has a type as RS pointed out. Should be Event Handler instead of Myhandler.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
MyCallBack rcb(my_handler,&MyHandler<MyEvent_t>::on_event);
```

is a problem since `on_event` takes an argument. The member function pointer expected in the constructor of `MyCallBack()` does not take any arguments.

The following works for me from a compile/build point of view. You'll have to figure out how to make it work for a semantic point of view.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyCallBack
{
   private:
      class Callback
      {
         public:
            virtual ~Callback() { }
            virtual void call() = 0;
      };

      template <typename T>
         class ClassCallback : public Callback
      {
         private:
            T*      object;
            void (T::*callback)();

         public:
            ClassCallback(T* obj, void (T::*clbk)()) : object(obj), callback(clbk) {}
            virtual void call() { (object->*callback)(); }
      };

   private:
      Callback*       callback;

   public:
      MyCallBack() : callback(NULL) { }
      ~MyCallBack() { delete callback; }

      template <typename T>
         MyCallBack(T* obj, void (T::*clbk)())
         {
            callback = new ClassCallback<T>(obj,clbk);
         }

      void operator () ()
      {
         callback->call();
      }
};

typedef enum {
   EVENT1 = 1,
   EVENT2 = 2,
   EVENT3 = 4,
   EVENT4 = 8
} MyEvent_t;

template <class EventT> 
class EventHandler
{
   public:
      void event() { on_event(EventT()); }
      virtual void on_event(EventT _event) = 0;
};

class MyHandler:public EventHandler<MyEvent_t>{

   virtual void on_event(MyEvent_t _event){

      switch(_event){

         case EVENT1:
            break;

         case EVENT2:
            break;

         default:
            break;
      }
   }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   EventHandler<MyEvent_t> *my_handler = new MyHandler();
   MyCallBack rcb(my_handler,&EventHandler<MyEvent_t>::event);

   // to check the callback
   rcb();

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achive is the action pattern.
Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

And now to the implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Action {
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

struct SomeAction : public Action {
    void execute() {
        std::cout << "SomeAction" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct SomeOtherAction : public Action {
    void execute() {
        std::cout << "SomeOtherAction" << std::endl;
    }
};

class EventHandler {

    std::unique_ptr<Action> action; // The unique ptr will delete action if the event handler is destroyed

public:
    EventHandler() :
        action(new SomeAction())
    {

    }
    void setAction(Action* newAction) {
        action = std::unique_ptr<Action>(newAction);
    }
    void eventCalled() {
        // This function is invoked from the outside if the event happens
        action->execute();
    }
};

int main() {
    EventHandler eventHandler;

    //Some event is called
    eventHandler.eventCalled(); // Output "SomeAction"


    // We change the action later in time
    eventHandler.setAction(new SomeOtherAction());
    // Another Event gets called
    eventHandler.eventCalled(); // Output "SomeOtherAction"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it's unclear to you, how to map from the Event to the action (or possible multiple actions), feel free to leave a comment.